# Trouble Installing Egit in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Super noob here, but I am trying to install EGit in Eclipse Kepler for OS X. Using the eclipse market place, after clicking on it, and pressing install, it says "There is nothing to update."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EGit is already provided in the default installation of Eclipse Kepler - see http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr